# "in how to" or "on how to"?

Tags: prepositions, collocation

When to add in or on followed by how to (same case when it is followed by what, which)

Examples:

Here see instructions ***in how to*** enable 3D option on your TV.

The problem lies ***in how to*** put this concept into practice.

That means they need training ***in how to*** work more quickly .

Computer documentation typically  includes instructions ***on how to*** open the case.

It  offers challenging recommendations ***on how to*** move the reform process forward.

There is no  statewide policy ***on how to*** handle children  of prisoners.

Comment: I think "in" goes with the verb in sentence 2 ("lies in"), and is an error in sentence 1 (no native speaker would construct this sentence), and questionable in sentence 3. "On" sounds more natural to me (a native speaker).

Answer (score 1):

Ignore *how to blah blah blah*, because it’s a red herring.  In fact, you should replace *how to blah blah blah* with *red herrings* in your examples to figure out how to choose the right preposition.

That way you’ll see that all that matters is which proposition collocates with the word before it:

1. Here see **instructions in** red herrings.
2. The problem **lies in** red herrings.
3. That means they need **training in** red herrings.
4. Computer documentation typically includes **instructions on** red herrings.
5. It offers challenging **recommendations on** red herrings.
6. There is no statewide **policy on** red herrings.

So look at each preceding word: instructions and training both collocate with either, depending; policies one normally finds on red herrings, not in them; and so on and so forth.

Your *how to blah blah blah* is irrelevant outside a red herring, and inside a red herring it’s too dark to read anyway, so don’t worry about it.